# How do I enable Popover on launching my app?

Tags: uipopovercontroller, uipopover, ios5.1

I would like to enable Popover controller, right on the launch of my application in the portrait mode. Kindly give me some points to note down, I'm a newbie.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a lot with my code, i found this...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [masterPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown animated:YES];
    }   
}
```